# Prove that the lines joining the midpoints of opposite edges of the tetrahedron ABCD bisect each other

Tags: vectors

The points A, B, C, D have position vectors **a**, **b**, **c** and **d** respectively. Prove that the lines joining the midpoints of opposite edges of the tetrahedron ABCD bisect each other and give the position vector of the point of intersection.

I have started by working out the position vectors of E and F:

**b** + $\vec BA$  = **a**

so $\vec BA$  = **a** - **b** and position vector of E is $\frac{(a - b)}{2}$

and that for F is $\frac{d - c}{2}$.

But I can proceed no further.

[image]

Comment: The position vector of E is actually $(a+b)/2$ (being the midpoint of $A$ and $B$). Same comment about $F$. You can similarly find $G$ and $H$ and then check if the midpoints of $EF$ and $GH$ coincide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M_1$ be the midpoint of $[EF]$ and $M_2$ the midpoint of $[GH]$. Let us prove that $M_1=M_2$.

The following sum $$\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}+\vec{OD}$$

can be written in two ways:

$$1) \ \ (\vec{OA}+\vec{OB})+(\vec{OC}+\vec{OD})=2\vec{OE}+2\vec{OF}=4\vec{OM_1}$$

$$2) \ \ (\vec{OA}+\vec{OC})+(\vec{OB}+\vec{OD})=2\vec{OH}+2\vec{OG}=4\vec{OM_2}$$

Idintifying these results, one gets $\vec{OM_1}=\vec{OM_2}$, therefore $M_1=M_2$.

Consequently, the position vector is:

$$\vec{OM_1}=\vec{OM_2}=\dfrac14(\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}+\vec{OD})$$

Remark: This issue, like many others, is based on a barycentric reasoning: if $A,B,C,D$ have weight $1$, midpoints $E$ and $F$ for example have weights $2$, therefore one can concentrate the total weight, $4$: on $M_1$, the midpoint of midpoints.

Comment: Thank you.  How do you code for your vector arrow? I used \vec but it only covers first letter.

Comment: @Steve Harris It is indeed \vec, immediately followed by curly brackets enclosing whatever you want to be placed under the arrow.

Answer (score 1):

There is mistake in your attempt.

We have to find $\vec{OE}$ which will be $\frac{a+b}{2}$ and not $\vec{BE}$ or $\vec{EA}$ which is $\frac{a-b}{2}$ as you calculated.

Similarly, position vector of $F$ will be $\frac{c+d}{2}$.

Midpoint of $EF$ will be $\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$.

You can do the same $HG$.